# Kotlin async not running tasks parallelly

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I was trying Kotlin coroutines using a test file. What I observed is that the async{..} block , completes and then the next async block starts.

```
 @Test
  fun `xyz`() {

    runBlocking {
      val x = async {
        x()
      }
      val y = async {
        y()
      }
      val z = async {
        z()
      }
      println("x, y, z -> ${x.await()} , ${y.await()}, ${z.await()} ")
    }


  }

  fun x() = "x".also {
    repeat(1000) {
      println("waiting for network response.")
    }
    println("returning x")
  }

  fun y() = "y".also { println("returning y") }
  fun z() = "z".also { println("returning z") }
```

In this code block I can see "returning y" and "returning z" only gets printed after the call to x() completes. Thats not how I expect Kotlin to run things parallelly. Could you please tell me the change I need to do to run the three calls concurrently or not wait for one to complete.
PS - The code in test method can be run directly on main as well. :)

Comment: The `ContinuationInterceptor` of the `CoroutineScope` of the running coroutine created by the `runBlocking` block, has just a single thread to work with, therefore the x/y/z tasks are not executed in parallel

Comment: We can achieve concurrency by calling `yield()` under the x/y/z `async` blocks; to achieve parallel execution we will have to change the `ContinuationInterceptor`, for example by using `withContext(Dispatcher.Default){ ... }` or `withContext(newFixedThreadPoolContext(3, "pool name")){ ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question and the reason why you are not getting the expected asynchronous behavior comes from your `runBlocking` function and the `BlockingEventLoop` it creates as context. When running coroutines with this dispatcher, you will only work in a single `Thread`. Though technically `async` launches coroutines asynchronously, for your example, you'll only see this behaviour when performing non blocking operations like `delay` and this is only because `delay` schedules but this is of course not what you are looking for. The scope contexts you may be interested in for `async` to work are `IO`, `Default` or `Unconfined`, but I think in your case `Default` applies best. Keep in mind that unit tests usually need to start a blocking context like with `runBlocking` or `runTest` and so using a `coroutineScope` may work only if you are already in a coroutine scope (i.e. in a `suspend` function or withing a scope started with `runBlocking`) and if the context is already non-blocking. Here are 3 different versions of your own code with 3 different examples: a blocking one and two non-blocking with 2 different styles.

```
@Test
fun `should xyz synchronously in spite of async`() {
    runBlocking {
        val x = async {
            "x".also {
                repeat(1000) {
                    println("waiting for network response.")
                }
                println("returning x")
            }
        }
        val y = async {
            "y".also { println("returning y") }
        }
        val z = async {
            "z".also { println("returning z") }
        }
        println("x, y, z -> ${x.await()} , ${y.await()}, ${z.await()} ")
        println(coroutineContext)
    }
}

@Test
fun `should xyz asynchronously because of non-blocking with explicit Dispatchers_IO`() {
    runBlocking {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                val x = async {
                    "x".also {
                        repeat(1000) {
                            println("waiting for network response.")
                        }
                        println("returning x")
                    }
                }
                val y = async {
                    "y".also { println("returning y") }
                }
                val z = async {
                    "z".also { println("returning z") }
                }
                println("x, y, z -> ${x.await()} , ${y.await()}, ${z.await()} ")
                println(coroutineContext)
            }
    }
}
@Test
fun `should xyz asynchronously because of non-blocking  with coroutineScope`():Unit = runBlocking {
            coroutineScope {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                    val x = async {
                        "x".also {
                            repeat(1000) {
                                println("waiting for network response.")
                            }
                            println("returning x")
                        }
                    }
                    val y = async {
                        "y".also { println("returning y") }
                    }
                    val z = async {
                        "z".also { println("returning z") }
                    }
                    println("x, y, z -> ${x.await()} , ${y.await()}, ${z.await()} ")
                    println(coroutineContext)
                }.join()
            }

}
```

Note that, as suggested by @Joffrey, although the examples are used to make clear points about `contexts` and `scopes` in `Kotlin` coroutines, the following example would be the most correct one to implement in regards to respecting a concept very important in coroutines called `structured concurrency`. This is a bit more complex concept to understand, but in general we should avoid context switching when it is not necessary:

```
@Test
fun `should xyz asynchronously because of non-blocking with explicit Dispatchers_IO`()  = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default){
            val x = async {
                "x".also {
                    repeat(1000) {
                        println("waiting for network response.")
                    }
                    println("returning x")
                }
            }
            val y = async {
                "y".also { println("returning y") }
            }
            val z = async {
                "z".also { println("returning z") }
            }
            println("x, y, z -> ${x.await()} , ${y.await()}, ${z.await()} ")
            println(coroutineContext)
        }
```

Also make sure to consider using assertions in these tests. They are not complete. They are only focused on anwering your question.

Comment: The last snippet doesn't really make sense, as you're not using `coroutineScope` at all. Also, creating a `CoroutineScope` on the spot makes you escape structured concurrency and is really not recommended

Comment: In the second snippet, `withContext` is redundant, you could just pass your dispatcher to `runBlocking` directly, or to the `async`s directly.

Comment: @Joffrey, This is a test example. Structured concurrency isn't important for the test. We are evaluating if the `async` works. Structured concurrency has nothing to do with answering this question. The `withContext` is not redundant. If you run this code wihtout it, it will inherit the context of `runBlocking` removing the asynchronous effect. There will be a `BlockingEventLoop` instead of the `Dispatchers.Default`. Try running the code to understand how this works.

Comment: I'm sorry I think you misunderstood me. I mean instead of `runBlocking`+`withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` you should just use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }`. This doesn't need extra nesting. Regarding structured concurrency, you're answering a question from a beginner, so it's important to avoid using bad practices because beginners cannot easily distinguish the "shortcuts" you took to answer the question from the actual answer

Comment: And also @Joffrey, the whole point is to show that `coroutineScope` just like that will not work as suggested by @MichaS. In the meantime I tested that `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default)`. I didn't know that was possible but I have to say, and I'm talking about semantics here, that if its `runBlocking` it should be, well blocking... This trick is great that it works but it is bad semantics. It is not a critic to you, I'm actually glad you pointed that out, but it sill bad semantics imo.

Comment: @Joffrey, wouldn't you agree also that structured concurrency is bit of too much of a deep dive into the world of coroutines for beginners? I mean eventually they have to go in there, but it can be greatly confusing as well if the basics aren't there and imo, my example helps to make a bridge between the complete unknown and becoming familiar with coroutines. But I know you have a different opinion. But I also think that deep inside we agree with most of things and we have a very similar knowledge of coroutines 

Comment: I think you're confusing things here. `runBlocking` blocks the calling thread no matter what dispatcher you use inside it, that's why it's named this way: "run this snippet while blocking the current thread". With no dispatcher specified, it uses the blocked thread as an event loop. With a dispatcher specified, the blocked thread is just blocked, and the other dispatcher is used in the context inside the lambda. Still blocking. No semantic issue. Running things in parallel or not inside the lambda is irrelevant.

Comment: *wouldn't you agree also that structured concurrency is bit of too much of a deep dive* - of course. My point is really not to do a lesson on structured concurrency in this answer. My point is to avoid showing examples that don't respect it, which you could do. There is no need to escape structured concurrency here to make your points about the dispatcher.

Comment: @Joffrey, you'll find a lot of people that read `runBlocking` as "here comes a blocking coroutine!!" not as the calling `Thread` gets blocked. It doesn't also help that by default you get a blocking event loop. This is why I dislike this semantics. But thank you so much for actively participant on my response. I really appreciate this because then I can take this into account for my further reactions and I have learned something great with your comments on this!

Comment: And hopefully as the last comment on this, I have updated my response with your suggestion @Joffrey. I leave my original examples because they make points that I cannot make with the correct, or "correcter" way of implementing such tests and I hope you understand that.